# Regarding complex SQL design SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my table look like
[image]

i have to show data Part Name wise

```
Part Name    Time          Incoming    Outgoing    Transfer
---------    ------------  --------    --------    ---------
Sales        9:00 - 9:30      1           4           6
Sales        9:30 - 10:00     4           5           7
Sales        10:30 - 11:00    8           7           2
Michel       9:00 - 9:30      2           40          16
Michel       9:30 - 10:00     5           15          17
```

i have to show data party wise and time wise

i am not very good in complex sql development but got a help from one guy. his sql look like

```
DECLARE     @StartTime datetime = '2015-06-09 09:00:00',
            @EndTime datetime = '2015-06-09 18:00:00',
            @Interval int = 30 -- this can be changed.

DECLARE     @PartyIntervals TABLE (
            Party1Name      VARCHAR(500),
            StartRange      DATETIME,
            EndRange        DATETIME) 

DECLARE     @CSVIntervals   TABLE (
            Party1Name      VARCHAR(500),
            Incoming        INT,
            StartRange      DATETIME) 

;WITH cSequence AS
(
    SELECT
       @StartTime AS StartRange, 
       DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, @StartTime) AS EndRange
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      EndRange, 
      DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, EndRange)
    FROM cSequence 
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, @Interval, EndRange) < @EndTime
)


INSERT INTO @PartyIntervals
SELECT      Party1Name, 
            StartRange,
            EndRange 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Party1Name FROM tridip_Interval) A, cSequence ORDER BY Party1Name;
--SELECT * FROM @PartyIntervals ORDER BY Party1Name

INSERT INTO @CSVIntervals
SELECT  Party1Name,
        count(*) as incoming,
        CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) AS StartRange
FROM    tridip_Interval
WHERE   direction='I'
GROUP   BY CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0), Party1Name

SELECT  P.Party1Name,
        P.StartRange,
        P.EndRange,
        IsNull(Incoming , 0) AS Incoming
FROM    @PartyIntervals P LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        @CSVIntervals A ON  A.Party1Name = P.Party1Name AND P.StartRange = A.StartRange
ORDER BY  P.Party1Name,P.StartRange
```

this calculation is not clear

```
CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) AS StartRange
why 48 is used ?
```

### see this part too

```
INSERT INTO @CSVIntervals
SELECT  Party1Name,
        count(*) as incoming,
        CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) AS StartRange
FROM    tridip_Interval
WHERE   direction='I'
GROUP   BY CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0), Party1Name
```

here only incoming related data is getting inserted in `CSVIntervals` table but i need to also insert outgoing and transfer data for all part in same sql. this is not getting clear how to add more sql to insert outgoing and transfer related data?

if anyone could understand my requirement then please help me to form the sql as a result i will get my desire result.

thanks

### EDIT

i try to write this sql

```
INSERT INTO @CSVIntervals
SELECT  Party1Name,
        count(*) as incoming,
        CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) AS StartRange
FROM    tridip_Interval
WHERE   direction='I'
GROUP   BY CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0), Party1Name,

SELECT  Party1Name,
        count(*) as OutGoing,
        CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) AS StartRange
FROM    tridip_Interval
WHERE   direction='O'
GROUP   BY CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0), Party1Name,

SELECT  Party1Name,
        count(*) as Transfer,
        CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) AS StartRange
FROM    tridip_Interval
WHERE   direction='T'
GROUP   BY CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(Convert(datetime, [Call Start]) AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0), Party1Name
```

which is not working but i want to insert data for outgoing and transfer too like incoming data.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: see this section specially "see this part too" there u will see sql where i need to add more sql which will insert data for outgoing, call transfer etc

Comment: see my Edit area and come with suggestion please.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does it not produce the desired output? Does it cause your server to turn into a chicken and strut around the server room? I can help but you have to provide some details. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

It seems your SQL in EDIT would work to select all of the data if you use a UNION ALL between the three parts.
So try:

```
Insert Into @CSVIntervals
Query 1
union all
Query 2
union all
Query 3
```